# doctrine:migrations:diff generates 2 tables instead of one for ManyToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have two entities: `product` and `tag` connected by many-to-many relation.

Here is a part of `Product` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_tag")
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
private $tags;
```

and the similar at `Tag`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="tags")
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
 private $products;
```

The issue is when I generate migration using `php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff` I get both `product_tag` and `tag_product` generated. While I expect to get only the first one.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the Doctrine documentation ([Association Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html) > [Owning Side and Inverse Side](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-side-and-inverse-side)):

> The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its owning side by use of the mappedBy attribute of the [...] ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute designates the field in the entity that is the owner of the relationship.
>
> The owning side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its inverse side by use of the inversedBy attribute of the [...] ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute designates the field in the entity that is the inverse side of the relationship.

Basically you cannot use *inversedBy* in both entities. You should use it on the *owning side*. *mappedBy* should be used on the other side.

Read: [Picking Owning and Inverse Side](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#picking-owning-and-inverse-side)